# how to disable webview for a while in android

Tags: android, webview

Assume i have 10 web page. First time im loading 1st page and the next page will be loaded when user swipes the screen.so i incrementing web page count when the user swipes the screen. but problem is while loading a page if user swipes the screen many times then web view loades the page  that is incremented by the **unnecessary swipe done by the user while loading**.. So
i want to disable the user to touch the webview screen while page loading . how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I get from your description is that if user swipe from Page 1 to Page 2 and the page is loading in the mean time if user swipe 3 times then it will load Page 2,3,4,5 and you want disable swipe at unless Page 2 has been loaded. If I am correct then below is my solution

In `onfling()` method check for `boolean` that whether the page is completely loaded or not if not then return without further processing and I suppose your code for downloading the code will not run. This boolean must be set false before you call the downloading method and set to true where the downloading is finished.

Apart from this I will suggest to load that particular page on which the user finally scrolls to rather than disabling the swipe for that you will have to do nothing `onFling` just check whether the `downloader thread` is alive for the last page or not if yes interrupt it and start it again for the current page I think this approach is more user friendly

Comment: you solved my one part of problem but another part is after loading a page im displaying horizontally. and  the current visible screen is called current page. here no matter of loading a page it about scrolling a page